# How to execute a thread when execute is protected?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, private

I have a thread:

```
    type
  TThreadBackUp = class( TThread )
  protected
    procedure Execute(); override;
  public
    var DBName : string;
  end;
```

I use it to back up a database that I use in my program like this:

```
procedure TThreadBackUp.Execute();

var
  backUpFile : string;

begin
  with frmMain do
  begin
    backUpFile := odlgOpenBackUp.FileName;

    MSQChanges.SQL.Text := 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + DBName +
      ' TO DISK = ' + QuotedStr(backUpFile) +
      ' WITH CHECKSUM, INIT';
    MSQChanges.Execute;
  end;
end;
```

How can I call the thread when my execute procedure is private?

Comment: Call `Start` method to start a thread. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TThread.Start

Comment: You don't call `Execute`, the runtime does that, from the new thread. You just create the thread instance and it calls `Execute` in that thread.

Comment: Also, don't be surprised if you have issues trying to push database code onto background threads. This can be tricky to do.

Comment: Call `Start` (as said) or create a new descendant class with `Execute` redefined.
Also you must create a new connection for each thread to avoid errors. Connections cannot be shared because they are not thread-safe.

Comment: VCL components (e.g. TForm) are not thread-safe, so I would not recommend using `frmMain` in `TThreadBackUp.Execute()` method.